# How do you obtain the reference count of an object in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I would like find out the current reference count of an object in xcode. ANyone know to get that information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call the `retainCount` method on any object.  While debugging in GDB, you can use the print command.  E.g.:

```
p [anObject retainCount]
```

Comment: However, bear in mind that retainCount is unreliable, especially when dealing with autoreleased objects. Here's what [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retainCount) says on the issue.

Comment: While this answers the question, **the absolute retain count of an object is fairly universally useless**.

Answer (score 6):

For `Swift`:

```
p CFGetRetainCount(object)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!